# How to apply Triplet Loss for a ResNet50 based Siamese Network in Keras or Tf 2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a `ResNet` based `siamese` network which uses the idea that you try to minimize the `l-2` distance between 2 images and then apply a sigmoid so that it gives you `{0:'same',1:'different'}` output and based on how far the prediction is, you just flow the gradients back to network but there is a problem that updation of gradients is too little as we're changing the distance between `{0,1}` so I thought of using the same architecture but based on `Triplet Loss`.

```
    I1 = Input(shape=image_shape)
    I2 = Input(shape=image_shape)

    res_m_1 = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=I1, pooling='avg')
    res_m_2 = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=I2, pooling='avg')

    x1 = res_m_1.output
    x2 = res_m_2.output
    # x = Flatten()(x) or use this one if not using any pooling layer

    distance = Lambda( lambda tensors : K.abs( tensors[0] - tensors[1] )) ([x1,x2] )
    final_output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(distance)

    siamese_model = Model(inputs=[I1,I2], outputs=final_output)
 
    siamese_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(),metrics['acc'])

    siamese_model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=1000,epochs=10,validation_data=validation_data)
```

So how can I change it to use the `Triplet Loss function`? What adjustments should be done here in order to get this done? One change will be that I'll have to calculate

```
res_m_3 = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=I2, pooling='avg')
x3 = res_m_3.output
```

One thing  found in tf docs is `triplet-semi-hard-loss` and is given as:

`tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()`

> As shown in the paper, the best results are from triplets known as "Semi-Hard". These are defined as triplets where the negative is farther from the anchor than the positive, but still produces a positive loss. To efficiently find these triplets we utilize online learning and only train from the Semi-Hard examples in each batch.

Another implementation of `Triplet Loss` which I found on Kaggle is: [Triplet Loss Keras](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishpatel26/triplet-loss-network-for-humpback-whale-prediction)

Which one should I use and most importantly, **HOW**?

P.S: People also use something like: `x = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)` after `model.output`. Why is that?  What is this doing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Triplet Loss, but can you say if any of these examples correspond to whatever "Triplet Loss" is? I'm not qualified to say what is or isn't Triplet Loss, but if it's [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletHardLoss), I can definitely show you how it can be used.

Comment: Can you tell me show `Triplet Loss` based `Siamese` Network can be built? Using my Existing or another some other architecture?

Comment: As I mentioned in your recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579247/how-does-the-tensorflows-tripletsemihardloss-and-triplethardloss-and-how-to-use/65590426#65590426), [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet) does a great job show you how to using the `TripletSemiHardLoss`, so did still have this problem when using it?

Comment: I asked this question way before that one. Can You please tell me how can I make **either the dataset** so that I can directly use these losses in  `model.compile()` **Or make a  Hard/semi dataset manually** and pass in the simple `triplet Loss`? I'll award the bounty to you. I got you answer from there. I have left a few comments though for curiosity.

Comment: See if this answer on stack overflow helps - [How does the Tensorflow's TripletSemiHardLoss and TripletHardLoss and how to use with Siamese Network?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590426/7610724)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579247/how-does-the-tensorflows-tripletsemihardloss-and-triplethardloss-and-how-to-use/65590426?noredirect=1#comment115968120_65590426), and with role of `TripletSemiHardLoss` in mind, we could do following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

BATCH_SIZE = 32
LATENT_DEM = 128

def _normalize_img(img, label):
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.
    return (img, label)

train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

# Build your input pipelines
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
resNet50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=inputs, pooling='avg')
outputs = layers.Dense(LATENT_DEM, activation=None)(resNet50.output) # No activation on final dense layer
outputs = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(outputs) # L2 normalize embedding

siamese_model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Compile the model
siamese_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())

# Train the network
history = siamese_model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=3)
```

Comment: PS: I try to show you the outputs, but I cannot finish training it in short time for even one epoch with my laptop or at Colab, it's just too slow when using  ResNet50 : (

Comment: But you have used just one Network. Right?

Comment: Yes, one net is enough, `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss` take care all the details

Comment: the out of the network is 128 ?