# How does the Tensorflow's TripletSemiHardLoss and TripletHardLoss and how to use with Siamese Network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

As much as I know that `Triplet Loss` is a Loss Function which decrease the distance between anchor and positive but decrease between anchor and negative. Also, there is a margin added to it.

So for EXAMPLE LEt us Suppose: a `Siamese Network`, which gives embeddings:

```
anchor_output = [1,2,3,4,5...] # embedding given by the CNN model
positive_output = [1,2,3,4,4...]
negative_output= [53,43,33,23,13...]
```

And I think I can get the triplet loss such as: (I think I have to make it as loss using Lambda Layer or so)

```
# calculate triplet loss
d_pos = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_output - positive_output), 1)
d_neg = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_output - negative_output), 1)

loss = tf.maximum(0., margin + d_pos - d_neg)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

So what on the earth is:
[tfa.losses.TripletHardLoss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletHardLoss) and
[tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss)

As much as I know, Semi and hard are type of data generation techniques for `Siamese Techniques` which push the model to learn more.

**MY Thinking**: As I have learned it in [This Post](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss), I think you can do:

1. Generate a Batch of say 3 images and make a pair of 3 having `27` images
2. Discard every **invalid** pair (all i,j,k should be unique). Remaining Batch `B`
3. Get the embeddings on each pair in batch `B`

So I think `HardTripletLoss` takes account of only those 3 images per batch which had **Biggest** Anchor-Positive distance and **Lowest** Anchor- Negative distance.

And for `Semi Hard`, I think it discards all the losses calculated by every image pair where the distance was 0.

if not, Could someone please correct me and tell me how these can be used. (I know we can use it inside `model.complie()` but my question is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What is `TripletHardLoss`?

This loss follow the ordinary `TripletLoss` form, but using the maximum positive distance and minimum negative distance plus the margin constant within the batch when computing the loss, as we can see in the formula:

[image]

Look into [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.11.2/tensorflow_addons/losses/triplet.py#L201-L299) of `tfa.losses.TripletHardLoss` we can see above formula been implement exactly:

```
# Build pairwise binary adjacency matrix.
adjacency = tf.math.equal(labels, tf.transpose(labels))
# Invert so we can select negatives only.
adjacency_not = tf.math.logical_not(adjacency)

adjacency_not = tf.cast(adjacency_not, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
# hard negatives: smallest D_an.
hard_negatives = _masked_minimum(pdist_matrix, adjacency_not)

batch_size = tf.size(labels)

adjacency = tf.cast(adjacency, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

mask_positives = tf.cast(adjacency, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32) - tf.linalg.diag(
    tf.ones([batch_size])
)

# hard positives: largest D_ap.
hard_positives = _masked_maximum(pdist_matrix, mask_positives)

if soft:
    triplet_loss = tf.math.log1p(tf.math.exp(hard_positives - hard_negatives))
else:
    triplet_loss = tf.maximum(hard_positives - hard_negatives + margin, 0.0)

# Get final mean triplet loss
triplet_loss = tf.reduce_mean(triplet_loss)
```

Note the `soft` parameter in `tfa.losses.TripletHardLoss` are **not** using following formula to calculate the ordinary `TripletLoss`:

[image]

Because as we can see in above source code, it still using maximum positive distance and minimum negative distance, it determine using the soft margin or not

### What is `TripletSemiHardLoss`?

This loss also follow the ordinary `TripletLoss` form, positive distances is same as in  ordinary `TripletLoss` and negative distance using **semi-hard negative**:

> Minimum negative distance among which are at least greater than the
> positive distance plus the margin constant, if no such negative
> exists, uses the largest negative distance instead.

i.e we want first find negative distance that satisfies following condition:

[image]

`p` for positive and `n` for negative, if wan can't find the negative distance that satisfies this condition then we using largest negative distance instead.

As we can see above condition process clear in [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.11.2/tensorflow_addons/losses/triplet.py#L69-L198) of `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss`, where `negatives_outside` is distance that satisfies this condition and `negatives_inside` is largest negative distance:

```
# Build pairwise binary adjacency matrix.
adjacency = tf.math.equal(labels, tf.transpose(labels))
# Invert so we can select negatives only.
adjacency_not = tf.math.logical_not(adjacency)

batch_size = tf.size(labels)

# Compute the mask.
pdist_matrix_tile = tf.tile(pdist_matrix, [batch_size, 1])
mask = tf.math.logical_and(
    tf.tile(adjacency_not, [batch_size, 1]),
    tf.math.greater(
        pdist_matrix_tile, tf.reshape(tf.transpose(pdist_matrix), [-1, 1])
    ),
)
mask_final = tf.reshape(
    tf.math.greater(
        tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32), 1, keepdims=True
        ),
        0.0,
    ),
    [batch_size, batch_size],
)
mask_final = tf.transpose(mask_final)

adjacency_not = tf.cast(adjacency_not, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

# negatives_outside: smallest D_an where D_an > D_ap.
negatives_outside = tf.reshape(
    _masked_minimum(pdist_matrix_tile, mask), [batch_size, batch_size]
)
negatives_outside = tf.transpose(negatives_outside)

# negatives_inside: largest D_an.
negatives_inside = tf.tile(
    _masked_maximum(pdist_matrix, adjacency_not), [1, batch_size]
)
semi_hard_negatives = tf.where(mask_final, negatives_outside, negatives_inside)

loss_mat = tf.math.add(margin, pdist_matrix - semi_hard_negatives)

mask_positives = tf.cast(adjacency, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32) - tf.linalg.diag(
    tf.ones([batch_size])
)

# In lifted-struct, the authors multiply 0.5 for upper triangular
#   in semihard, they take all positive pairs except the diagonal.
num_positives = tf.math.reduce_sum(mask_positives)

triplet_loss = tf.math.truediv(
    tf.math.reduce_sum(
        tf.math.maximum(tf.math.multiply(loss_mat, mask_positives), 0.0)
    ),
    num_positives,
)
```

### How to use those loss?

Both loss expect `y_true` to be provided as 1-D integer `Tensor` with shape [batch_size] of multi-class integer labels. And embeddings `y_pred` must be 2-D float `Tensor` of l2 normalized embedding vectors.

Example code to prepare the inputs and labels:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

def _normalize_img(img, label):
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.
    return (img, label)

train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

# Build your input pipelines
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(16)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

# Take one batch of data
for data in train_dataset.take(1):
    print("Batch of images shape:\n{}\nBatch of labels:\n{}\n".format(data[0].shape, data[1]))
```

Outputs:

```
Batch of images shape:
(16, 28, 28, 1)
Batch of labels:
[8 4 0 3 2 4 5 1 0 5 7 0 2 6 4 9]
```

Following this [official tutorial about how to using `TripletSemiHardLoss` (`TripletHardLoss` as well) in general](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet) if you have problem when using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. This was the actual problem actually. Do you think my understanding of these `tf` losses are correct? I mean they are implementing `Online Triplet Mining` right? Where we don't even have to choose the triplets and losses takes care of that. Right?

Comment: I asked the question looking at the example. But the problem is that I can not see the structure of the data. I mean the have used `train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32)` for creating batch and then `train_dataset  = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)` for mapping to the function. I can not see how data is stored. Can you please tell me how data is structured? or a method by which I can see the internal structure of `train` , `labels` and `test etc

Comment: I update the answer, now you can see what structure of the data you should provide, and your understanding about `TripletHardLoss` is correct but `TripletSemiHardLoss` is not correct, check the quote in my answer for definition of `semi-hard negative`, if you care about the usage, then you may not want thinking too much of those detail like have to choose the triplets because those losses takes care of it

Comment: @Deshwal Talk to me if you still have questions

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Mean a lot. This is very detailed explanation. Could you please just post a dummy code to the other answer for a dummy `resnet Siamese` with this loss, so that I can award you the bounty. I got the idea how to create the dataset and use `Triplet Loss`

Comment: The data looks like the simple classification set with `Categorical Sparse CrossEntropy`.  I think I can build a dataset now for `N` classes.

Comment: @Deshwal Yes, exactly the sparse categorical, Glad to help, of course, I'll post a dummy code for just a moment, you have a good day : )

Comment: You can refer to this example as well: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet